# No Module Named Ipywidgets Error

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm new in Ipython and Jupyter Notebook. I installed the ipywidgets module in Jupyter Notebook by using Anaconda prompt window.

I tried:

```
pip install ipywidgets
```

It said that the requirements had already satisfied. Then I tried to import the module but received the "**ImportError: No module named ipywidgets**" error.

Then I tried:

```
conda install ipywidgets
```

It fetched some files from the "**api.anaconda.org**" site and installed the files. I exited from Jupyter Notebook and entered again. When I tried to import the modüle received the same "**ImportError: No module named ipywidgets**" error.

I have no idea what is wrong. How can I import this modüle to Jupyter Notebook and Anaconda ?

Comment: What happens when you open a terminal Python, and import?

Comment: There is no problem with the teminal. I can import the modüle in terminal window. But ı can't import in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Do you perhaps have more than a single Python installation (maybe 2 and 3)? Which OS is it? If on linux, what is the output of `ls /usr/bin/python*`?

Comment: My OS is Windows 10. I installed the Python 2 and Python 3 kernels together on the Jupyter Notebook. When I used the "conda install ipywidgets" command it installed it on the Python 2. While I was trying to import the module current kernel was Python 2 on the Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Well, I'm stumped. Good luck to you.

Comment: If you activate the environment you installed it into, can you run `ipython` in a command prompt and try importing ipywidgets? If that works (or at least gives a different error), your Python 2 kernel may not be using the same environment that you installed it into.

Comment: I unistalled Python 2 and Python 3 kernels both . Than I installed them again. While installing at the same time I upgraded the pip version. Now there isn't any problem. But I haven't  been able to find  the source of the error so far.

Comment: @ThomasK how can one check what environment the Python2 kernel is using? I have the same problem but unable to fix it yet.

Comment: `sys.executable` gives you the location of the Python you're running in; that should show you which environment it's in.

Comment: I have the same problem when I use command notebook_login() and I install "pip install ipywidgets". It still not working